# How to increase the height of FCKEditor textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to increase the heigh of FCK Text Editor.
Here is the code I have:

```
<tr>
  <td  colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle">
      <textarea name="text" id="text" >
         <?php echo $curnote;?>
      </textarea>
 </td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
CKEDITOR.replace( 'text', { width:'90%' } );
</script>
```

If I am putting  `{ width:'90%', height:'90%' }`, it's Not working.

Can you please suggest me to overcome this issue? Please

Comment: % works for width, use pixel values for height

Comment: thnx slash .. it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config.js file add following code.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
 {

      config.height = '500px'; // here give your desired height value

};
```